# Styles not being overridden with image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a web page with a set of links I styled that lead you to other pages. One of these pages is a gallery of photos.

When I try to link the thumb-nail to the larger image, I get this black border about 2-3 pixels high and slightly wider than the thumbnail. I have tried everything to override and get rid of this, but nothing I do seems to work.

```
 a:link,a:visited {
display: inline;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-left: 30px;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration:none;
border: 2px solid black;
}

a:hover {
background-color: #3bb2cE;
border: 2px solid black;
transition-property: background-color;
transition-duration: 1s;    
}

a:active {
background-color: #3bb2cE;
border: 2px solid black;
}

.link2 a:link, .link2 a:hover; .link2 a:active {
margin: 10px;
border: none;
}
```

`link2` is what I am trying to override the CSS with. It's not working even in the HTML:

```
<a class="link2" href="images/stairs1.jpg"><img src="images/stairs1_thumb.jpg" /></a>
<a class="link2" href="images/staris2.jpg"><img src="images/stairs2_thumb.jpg" /></a>
```

Here is an image of what is happening:

[image: Image of my HTML page]

Answer (score 1):

If you can't remove the border, and you merely need to overwrite the border, use:

```
a.link2 {
    margin: 10px;
    border: none;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/x6cJx/) - it works.

Your other styling, (`.link2 a:link, .link2 a:hover; .link2 a:active`), wasn't being applied.
The selector, `.link2 a:link` is selecting an `a` elements, who is a link, and child of an element with class `.link2`.. this obviously doesn't work, as `.link2` is the `a` element you are trying to remove the border from.

Simply put, just use `a.link2`, which selects an `a` elements with class `.link2`.

As the demo demonstrates, this will effectively overwrite the initial styling, removing the border.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from your css

```
border: 2px solid black;
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to remove any css

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/bX4WH/1/

```
a:link, a:visited {
display: inline;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-left: 30px;
margin: 10px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration:none;
border: 2px solid black; /*for no border remove this*/
display:inline-block;   /*add this*/
}
```